# No sound from speakers on ASUS Zenbook UX3402ZA_Q409ZA

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, asus, headphones

I installed Ubuntu 23.04 on my ASUS Zenbook UX3402ZA_Q409ZA. I am able to hear sound when the headphones are connected however the internal speakers do not output sound when nothing is connected to the headphone jack. I have tried reloading alsa and installing pulse audio to change the levels but to no success. Any help would be appreciated!
Thank You!
-Aubury-

Comment: Related bug report (that claims "Sound doesn't work at all"): [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1981433)

Answer (score 2):

Please check solution (SSDT patch) described here: https://gist.github.com/lamperez/862763881c0e1c812392b5574727f6ff?permalink_comment_id=4531290#gistcomment-4531290

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, and seems to be the only fix in existence for specifically the UX3402ZA. Been looking for solutions for over 6 months, and happy to now have audio :)

Comment: I was struggling with the same problem for past 1 year. Finally got the sound working with this:

https://github.com/thor2002ro/asus_zenbook_ux3402za/tree/main

I also had to update to the mainline kernels to make this work. I am now using kernel 6.4.9

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can be that the correct channel is muted or its levels are set so low that no sound can be detected. How you can check if that's the case, is if you open `alsamixer` in the terminal, and you should see something like this.

[image]

Further instructions on how to use Alsamixer: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer

Comment: Thanks! I was able to launch that window inside my terminal and everything seems fine inside alsamixer. There were no channels with MM under them they are all un-muted and at full volume. I am still missing sound output though so I feel like maybe ubuntu hasn't detected the correct sound output?

Comment: Can you post what is the output of: pactl list | grep 'Active Port.*output.*'
...when you don't have anything in the headphone jack?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 22.04 with Zenbook UX5400Z.
My computer is set up to have dual boot with Windows.
I found a recomendation [here](https://www.linux.org/threads/solved-asus-zenbook-15-ux534f-realtek-hd-audio-problem.27384/post-122971) to disable fast boot in windows
(control panel -> power options -> Choose what the power buttons do -> Change settings that are currently unavailable -> Under 'Shutdown settings,' uncheck the 'Turn on fast startup' box)
This immediatly fixed the issue.