# No sound from built-in speakers, but headphones work right

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, asus

I've tried the 23.10 and 22.04 versions, but the problem still the same. There is no sound.

1. All the channels in alsamixer are enabled.
2. The output is set to *Speaker* and isn't muted.
3. I can see that the indicator in pavucontrol moves during playback, but in fact there is no sound.
4. There *is* sound in headphones. When plugging in the channel changes to *Headphones*
5. Kernel version 6.5.0-13-generic
6. sof-hda-dsp sound card
7. ASUS UX3402V

Please help me with this. I've killed a lot of time and tried every solution I found, but I've still had no luck.

pavucontrol:

[image: pavucontrol]

Comment: Does `pavucontrol` tell _Speaker_ is available?

Comment: @jarno yes, I think it is. Updated the question with a screenshot

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1467417/21005

Comment: Are you able to produce sound using any other way, like using other OS??

Comment: Thank you, but I tried the top answer and it didn't help.

Comment: @Ajay actually, no. I mean, I have sound in headphones and I'm pretty sure that this issue won't occur on Win. Do you mean that the speakers may be defective?

Comment: I guess UX3402V would need a kernel pach similar to the brother models have, see [patch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tiwai/sound.git/commit/?id=07058dceb038a4b0dd49af07118b6b2a685bb4a6)

Comment: You could file a bug report by `ubuntu-bug linux`